# Shield encrypted field, unencrypted results?

Tags: apex, soql, encryption, shield-encryption

If a field is encrypted with Shield, can we get the unencrypted value with Apex classes/SOQL statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shield Platform Encryption provides encryption for data *at rest*. While it does impact your ability to interact with the field data in specific ways primarily around sorting and aggregation (see [General Shield Platform Encryption Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_considerations_general.htm)), data from encrypted fields will be presented to your code in plaintext. Your code will never see the encrypted form of the data.